# Perform multiple left joins using Linq

Tags: linq, join

I have four tables. I want to perform multiple left join on a table as follows.

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on <condition1>
into join1
from subJoin1 in join1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join t3 in table3 on <condition2>
into join2
from subjoin2 in join2.DefaultIfEmpty()
join t4 in table4 on <condition3>
into join3
from subjoin3 in join3.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new

{
Field1 = t1.some_field,
Field2 =  t2.some_field,
Field3 =  t3.some_field,
Field4 =  t4.some_field,
}
```

My problem is the first left join alone works fine, but when left join is done consecutively, the t1 data row  is lost if a mapping cannot be found in t3, t4 etc.

Please help.

Comment: What type of LINQ? Most of the times you should use navigation properties in stead of joins.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `into` (at least right away)!

Something like

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on <inner_join_condition>
from t3 in table3.Where(<left_outer_join_condition>).DefaultIfEmpty()
...
select new
{
Field1 = t1.some_field,
Field2 = t3.some_field,
...
}
```

works usually pretty well!